# Request-Reply Database Model

Tags: java, mysql, sql, hibernate

I'm wondering about simple database model based on the interaction of requests and replies. The one request can have only one answer. There can be made another request based on the previous answer. It is needed to be able to iterate the all history - from the first request to the last reply. I've done a sample model:

```
Requests:            Reply:
| int id       |     | int id      |
| int parentID |     | String text |
| String text  |
| int answerID |
```

How can I improve it and make it more usable?

Comment: Why not keep a single table called `message` with `from_id` and `to_id`?

Comment: In the requests and the replies there is additional information which I've not included in the sample.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming a request can generate multiple replies.

```
Request
-------
Request ID
Request timestamp
Request text
```

Request ID is the primary (clustering) key.  It's an auto-incrementing integer or long.

You also define a non-unique index on request timestamp, descending.

```
Reply
-----
Reply ID
Request ID
Reply timestamp
Reply text
```

Reply ID is the primary (clustering) key.  It's an auto-incrementing integer or long.

You also define a non-unique index on (Request ID, Reply timestamp descending).   You may also define a non-unique index on (Reply timestamp descending, Request ID).  The first index is for all the replies for a request.  The second index is for all the replies in a time period (week , month).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I forgot to mention that one request can have only one answer. After that there can be made new request based on the previous answer. I updated the question.

Comment: @Ventsislav Marinov: I wish Stack Overflow worked that way.  One question, one answer.  You can use the same model I outlined.  You would just add a unique index in the Reply table on Request ID.